# What is the proper way to animate a child element in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

In my application I have a component that consists of a div with a background image and another div nested inside of it. Once the component is hovered the nested div will change its opacity to 85% and I want that to happen with a transition. I coded it and it worked fine when running my application in development mode, however, once my application was put into production this animation is completely ignored.

Also I want to mention that for this project I am using React v16.12, the latest version of Bootstrap and my application was created using Create React App.

I used chrome dev tools to check if it was happening at all and it indeed shows there but no visual effect is shown to the screen.

Also, there are some other animations in my application which are working fine.

This is the code of my component

```
const ProductShowcase = ({ img, title, link }) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-4 mb-4">
            <Link to={link}>
                <div className="fade-img" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${img})`}}>
                    <div className="superposed d-flex text-center align-items-center">
                        <p className="lead showcase-text">{title}</p>
                        <div className="overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And this is the CSS that I am applying to it

```
.fade-img{
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 1.8%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.superposed{
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay{
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2c3554;
    opacity: 0%;
    transition: opacity .25s;
    border-radius: inherit;
    position: absolute;
}

.fade-img p{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 150;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px grey;
}

.fade-img:hover .superposed .overlay{
    opacity: 85%;
}

.showcase-text{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
    .fade-img{
        height: 50px;
    }

    .showcase-text{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
}
```

I am aware it may be caused by some optimization made by React that I am not aware of, however I have not been able to find any information about it nor any similar case.

Comment: React dev vs. prod build shouldn't have an effect on the animation, which looks fine btw. Is something else running in the production build that could explain this? Are you minifying or running any css preprocessor? Do the classnames get mangled? Are you sure the classes are indeed getting applied properly when you inspect the elements with devtools

Comment: @RedMercury I am relatively new to React so I am still using Create React App. I am aware it does quite a few things with Webpack and Babel to run the app. But I am not sure what those things are.